# Why Nothing shows to my Recharts even though i'm throwing the order starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, recharts

I want to show the months and the total sales in the rechart but it just shows an empty chart. I'm also receiving the months in random order.

[image]

I'm trying to show here the previous months of sale to the present, so it should be starting  at May to November.

This is what I received.

[image]

statistics.js

```
const MONTHS = useMemo(
    () => [
        'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ],[]
)
useEffect(() =>{
    const getIncomeStats = async () =>{
        try {
            const res = await userRequest.get(`/order/previousSales/${id}`)
            res.data.map((item) => {
                setOrderStats(prev=>[
                    ...prev,
                    {name:MONTHS[item._id - 1], "Total Sales": item.total}
                    
                    ])
            })
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
    getIncomeStats()
},[MONTHS])
```

And then I throw it to the Chart Componenent

```
  <Chart data={orderStats} stroke="#76ff03" color="#00e676" />
```

Chart.jsx

```
const Chart = ({stroke, color, orderStats}) => {
    return (
          <AreaChart
            width={800}
            height={400}
            data={orderStats}
            margin={{
              top: 10,
              right: 30,
              left: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="name" />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke={stroke} fill={color} />
          </AreaChart>
      );
}
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve
[image]

I think I'm approaching the recharts wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer guys, thanks to @lamadev, if you're here I love you.

```
   useEffect(() =>{
        const getIncomeStats = async () =>{
            try {
                const res = await userRequest.get(`/order/previousSales/${id}`)
                const list = res.data.sort((a,b)=>{
                    return a._id - b._id
                })

                list.map((item) =>
                setOrderStats((prev) => [
                  ...prev,
                  { name: MONTHS[item._id - 1], "Total Sales": item.total },
                ])
              );
            } catch (error) {
            }
        }
        getIncomeStats()
    },[MONTHS])
```

This is the chart, I change it.

```
<LineChart width={1200} height={400} data={data}
  margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip />
  <Legend />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Total Sales" stroke="#8884d8" />
</LineChart>
```